# moving multiple images in iOS after being created programmatically using tags

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am trying to programmatically create multiple images then be able to move any of them around the view. I click a button and then I can move that image. I click the button again and I can move that image but no longer can move the first image created. I was trying to use tags.

header.

```
UIImageView *imageView;    
NSUInteger i;
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
```

implementation

```
@synthesize imageView;

-(IBAction)printTheImage:(id)sender{
    UIImageView *theImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animage.png"]];
    self.imageView = theImage;
    self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(500, 500, 200, 200);
    imageView.tag = i;
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
    i++;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if ([touch view]==self.imageView) 
        {
        if (ImageView.tag == 1){           
           self.imageView.center = location;
        }
        if (imageView.tag == 2){
           self.imageView.center = location;
        }
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{ 
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    i = 1;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: As per apple coding conventions, a variable name should start with lowercase letter. You should use `imageView` instead of `ImageView`. `ImageView` represents a class name and is confusing to use as a variable name.

Comment: the problem here is that you replaced previous reference of an UIImageView by the time you retained it using properties on the second  time function call, you need to save somehow the reference of the newly created object like an NSMutableArray, what I mean is your ImageView property can hold only 1 reference which will be the newly created object you made every time you call printTheImage: function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with from your code

```
//header
NSUInteger imageCount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *selectedImageView;

//implementation

@synthesize selectedImageView;

-(IBAction)printTheImage:(id)sender {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"animage"]];
    [imageView sizeToFit];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(500, 500, 200, 200);
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    imageView.tag = imageCount;
    [self.view addSubview: imageView];
    [imageView release];

    imageCount++;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    //iterate trough all images
    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
        //get image from tag
        UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag: i];
        //check which image was tapped
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageView.frame, [touch locationInView:self.view])) {
            NSLog(@"Image #%i was tapped",i);
            self.selectedImageView = imageView;
            //don't waste processor time for checking all other images, get the first and break the loop
            break;
    }
}
```

This is what moves the image:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    //move the tapped image
    self.selectedImageView.center = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}
```

Remeber to reset the image counter and set selectedImageView to nil on touches ended and touches canceled phase

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *imageViews;


@synthesize imageView;

-(IBAction)printTheImage:(id)sender{
    UIImageView *theImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animage.png"]];

    [self.imageViews adObject:theImage];

    theImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    theImage.frame = CGRectMake(500, 500, 200, 200);
    imageView.tag = [imageViews indexOfObject:theImage];
    [self.view addSubview:theImage];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSInteger viewIndex = [self.imageViews indexOfObject:[touch view]];
    if (viewIndex != NSNotFound) 

        UIView *theImage = self.imageViews[viewIndex];
        theImage.center = location;

    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{ 
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this approach works with gesture recognizer

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController {
        int tags;
    }

    - (IBAction)create:(id)sender;

    @end

        @implementation ViewController

        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            //Tag to start
            tags = 1;
        }

        - (IBAction)create:(id)sender
        {
            UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 200)];
            temp.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.jpg"];
            temp.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            temp.tag = tags;

            UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                  action:@selector(handlePan:)];

            UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

            [temp addGestureRecognizer:pan];
            [temp addGestureRecognizer:tap];
            [self.view addSubview:temp];

            tags++;
        }


        //This is just to check if the tags are working
        -(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
        {
            UIView *piece = recognizer.view;
            int index = piece.tag;
            NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tag:%i", index];

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"
                                                            message:msg
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }

        //Drag action
        -(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
        {
            UIView *piece = recognizer.view;

            if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
            {
                CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:[piece superview]];
                [piece setCenter:CGPointMake([piece center].x + translation.x, [piece center].y + translation.y)];
                [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[piece superview]];
                [self.view bringSubviewToFront:piece];
            }
        }

@end
```

already tested and working

good luck